# how to skip dirs that are mounted twice?

Tags: linux

I need to list a directory recursively but I want to skip subdirs that were already mounted.
There are 2 cases:

a) a filesystem was mounted twice, like in this example:

- "/dev/sda2" was mounted on "/mnt/mnt_point1"
- "/dev/sda2" was mounted on "/mnt/mnt_point2"
  I want to list "/mnt" but descend only in "/mnt/mnt_point1"

b) part of the file hierarchy was remounted somewhere else, with "mount --bind":

- "mount --bind /home/user/tmp/test /home/user/tmp/mounted_test"

I want to list "/home/user/tmp" but descend only in "test"

"statfs" and "statvfs" don't offer any information to discern if a dir was mounted twice.

One solution would be to read "/etc/mtab" (as "find" command does it) and perform some checks, but I think that this is pretty expensive (one has to read /etc/mtab every time one encounters a dir; if this file is read only when program starts, a mount could occur in between reads, so that the program will be inaccurate).

Another solution would be to filter kernel events (via libudev or Netlink) and do this reading of /etc/mtab only when a MOUNT event was issued.

Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jens: Removed it (and the C tag too) on the grounds that this is a question that isn't about either of those languages.

Comment: With most Unix variants, you cannot mount the same file system twice - the system won't let you.  Certainly not for local file systems; NFS might be different.  Are you sure that Linux allows double-mounting?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: yes as baudolino indicated, with the `-bind` option you can even mount just other directories. This gives you a feature as if you could do something like "temporary hardlinks" with directories.

Answer (score 1):

First of all reading `mtab` is not as expensive as you might think, if it doesn't change, linux will probably keep it in memory if you access it often.

But for your purpose, `mtab` probably will not contain the information that you are looking for. Parse `/proc/mounts` instead.

Comment: Actually, mtab contains also info about "mount --bind". Example:

cat /etc/mtab

/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw,noatime,user_xattr,commit=0 0 0

/dev/sda2 /mnt/mnt_point1 ext3 

/dev/sda2 /mnt/mnt_point2 ext3

/home/florin/tmp/to_mount/balance_trees /home/florin/tmp/to_mount/


and cat /proc/mounts 

/dev/root / ext3 

/dev/root /home/florin/tmp/to_mount/

/dev/sda2 /mnt/mnt_point1 ext3 

/dev/sda2 /mnt/mnt_point2 ext3

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @baudolino: yes it `may` contain that info, but it mustn't. `mount` can be told to not write an entry into `mtab`. `/proc/mounts` tells you what is real, without cheating. There is a para in the `man` page that explains the difference.